# React errors only displaying in the console

Tags: reactjs

My errors are only showing in the console. The webpage just becomes a blank white page. Anyone have a similar issue? I recently uninstalled my npm and reinstalled everything. Maybe this could be the cause?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: please provide more details and screenshot regarding the error.

Comment: In production build React does not show dev error screen (will show a white screen) but you can use a ErrorBounary => https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html to show errors in production.

Comment: @kiner_shah I was able to debug the errors . However, I can only view the errors in my terminal . Unlike before I was able to view the same error messages on the webpage as well.

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera after deleting my uninstalling my node package module this began once i reinstalled my react router dom .. Is there another one to achieve this without using errorBounary ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.